# Login system using Oledb Access

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

I made a login page were the employee type in employee email address and then their pin. The idea is for the program to check the email and the pin form a Access database to successfully log them in. This is the code that I used.

```
 private void Validate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\Users\\Baladi\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\CalUnderFoot\\CalUnderFoot\\UserPerm.mdb");           
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;

        string cmdStr = String.Format("select * from UserPermT where EmpEmail='{0}' and EmpPIN='{1}'", EmpEmailtxt.Text, EmpPINtxt.PasswordChar);

        con.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        cmd.Dispose();

        if (dr.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("fail");
        }

        dr.Dispose();
    }
```

When I enter the wrong email and pin I get a message saying "fail" which is what it supposed to do. BUT, when I enter the right email and pin I still get the "fail" message. What am I missing??
And yes I know... I am not supposed to store passwords in databases and I will encrypt them in due time.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not have the setup to test it myself, but have you tried to "not dispose" of the Command object ("cmd.Dispose();") before you call read?

Comment: Yeah I did.... same thing. I think it is because I used a passwordbox for my PIN (thus it is passchar and not txt) and the program is not able to read it into string.

Comment: Have you tried to open the connection after the cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, con); ?

Comment: Tried that and got an error that there is no open connection :/

Comment: what is EmpPINtxt.PasswordChar it is textbox or ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void Validate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\Users\\Baladi\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\CalUnderFoot\\CalUnderFoot\\UserPerm.mdb"))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from UserPermT where EmpEmail='"+EmpEmail.Text+"' and EmpPIN='"+EmpPIN.PasswordChar+"'", connection);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr= command.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("fail");
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    }
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca.aspx)

Comment: Nope it did not work. I told the program to check only for the email with the code that I previously posted and it worked! I think I have to figure out a way to convert PassChar into string.

Comment: what is EmPIN? is it a passwordbox?

Comment: seems to me that you are using the wrong property. In a passwordbox you should use .Password. PasswordChar is just the char that is replaced visually...in most cases is the '*' symbol.